# Compiling MySql plugin under Qt 5.14.2

Tags: mysql, qt

i'am using a Windows x64, i need to use Mysql 8 in QT 5.14.2( MinGW x64)

i've started installing MySQl driver as indicated :

2- then when, I am using:

```
cd $QTDIR/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql
```

3- and run:

```
qmake -- MYSQL_INCDIR="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include" "MYSQL_LIBDIR="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib"
```

I'm getting :

```
Project ERROR: Library 'mysql' is not defined.
```

in the log file it shows me that there's a missing file sybfront.h anyone knows how to solve this please

Answer (score 1):

You should replace '\' by '/', either paths will be invalid, even on Windows.

And one quote " is not closed in your code.

qmake parameters follows the same rules as pro file contents:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-project-files.html

Comment: thank you very much Ighor for your answer, the probleme is now solved